# NFC issue with Android 13, works fine in older android versions

Tags: nfc

My NFC application works fine in Android 12 and previous versions but fails in Android 13.
I could read tag header info but write to NFC tag send request and fails to read back response. I could not find any updates on NFC from Android release notes.
appreciate your support.

Thanks

tried checking in multiple android 13 devices, issue is same

Comment: Which of the multiple methods do you detect and trigger NFC with? Showing your code for NFC might help and you might try one of the other methods to work around the problem.

Comment: I **cannot confirm** that my own and other standard NFC apps have any problems while running on Android 13 (SDK 33). Tested with e.g. NXP's TagInfo.